# MediaRoute Dialog: Disconnect vs Stop

Tags: google-cast

I'm working on an App that sends audio and video content to a chromecast. But I don't want to stop the playback when we disconnect our Sender App.

In the mediaroute-v7 package we find reference to an option to either disconnect or stop the connection. In fact the button to disconnect is hidden on https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/mediarouter/res/layout/mr_media_route_controller_material_dialog_b.xml#L103 and to make it visible mediaroute-v7 gets the SelectedRoute and checks the boolean canDisconnect() on https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/39b32a9feea6b821d6a5c92202c400aa1f252200/v7/mediarouter/src/android/support/v7/app/MediaRouteControllerDialog.java#L259.

Is there any way to change the boolean value of canDisconnect(), so we can show the button, with VideoCastManager? Or how is supposed to get that button visible?

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are using CCL (since you'd mentioned VideoCastManager). The current dialog that you see there is put out by CCL and is not the one provided by the mediarouter framework (unless you have overridden getMediaRouteDialogFactory()). In CCL, you have an option to decide if you want to simply disconnect from the cast device or stop the running app on the cast device when you click on that "Stop Casting" in the dialog; by default it just disconnects you and to change that, you have to call setStopOnDisconnect(true) to force it to stop the app. That said, the most common behavior on the receiver side (the default and styled receivers follow that as well) is to stop the app if the last connected device intentionally disconnects (i.e. if the last connected device is disconnected due to, say, network disruption, it doesn't stop the app). This behavior can be controlled on the receiver side by overriding onSenderDisconnected(reason) callback there.

Comment: Yes I am, the thing is that I need the app to switch between several chromecast with one Sender app. I am using the styled receiver and I don't want to stop the playback while switching between Chromecasts. The suggestion you give can't achieve what I need.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by switching between multiple chromecasts. If you don't want to tear down the receiver even if the last sender is disconnected intentionally, then you would need to write your own receiver and overwrite the callback that I mentioned; the styled receiver is not suitable for  your usecase. With a custom receiver, you can disconnect from one chromecast and then connect to a second one and cast whatever is needed to that one.